# How do I change a list of customers with multiple lines, and details into a single account line with categories

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot

Example Table, Turn this

| CustID | CustName | SalesRepName | SalesRepSpecialty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACME Corp | Steve P | Servers |
| 1 | ACME Corp | Susy Q | Network |
| 1 | ACME Corp | John D | Storage |
| 2 | MicroStuff | Auntie Irma | Network |
| 3 | O-Rickle | Daddy Larry | Servers |

and turn this into

| CustId | CustName | Server | Network | Storage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ACME Corp | Steve P | Suzy Q | John D |
| 2 | MicroStuff |  | Auntie Irma |  |
| 3 | O-Rickle | Daddy Larry |  |  |

Is this possible to do in MS Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Crosstab Query Wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8#crosstab_wizard) in Access to create a [TRANSFORM statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/transform-statement-microsoft-access-sql):

```sql
TRANSFORM Max(Turn.SalesRepName) AS MaxOfSalesRepName
SELECT Turn.CustID, Turn.CustName
FROM Turn
GROUP BY Turn.CustID, Turn.CustName
PIVOT Turn.SalesRepSpecialty;
```

To get the ordering of the columns right, you can append this clause manually (before the `;`):

```sql
IN (Servers, Network, Storage)
```

This also has the advantage that these columns will be created even when the corresponding `SalesRepSpecialty` is missing; however, new values will not automatically be appended. If you create an Access Report based on this query, then you need a fixed set of columns to be able to add a field for them (unless you do some complex dynamic stuff in VBA).

Comment: Yes. But if you want to base a Report on this query, then you need fixed columns.

Comment: Any advice on then inserting this into a new table?

Comment: Store this query as named query and create an insert query based on this first query. Use the IN-clause in the crosstab query as you will need a fixed set of columns in the insert query.